# subdomain redirects to main domain per each page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect subdomain pages to new pages on the main domain. The last line to redirect the homepage breaks all the previous page redirects. It rewrites it like:

```
https://www.example.org/debt-help/do-debt-management-plans-work
```

**instead of**

```
https://example.org/get-out-of-debt/
```

But it only breaks when the #redirect the homepage is added to htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^debthelp\.example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^do-debt-management-plans-work/(.*)$ https://example.org/get-out-of-debt/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^debthelp\.example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^how-to-manage-your-debt/(.*)$ https://example.org/get-out-of-debt/$1 [L,R=301]

#redirect the homepage and 404s
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^debthelp\.example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/debt-help/$1 [L,R]
```

It seemed to be working in the past. Could server settings affect this from an update? It is a wordpress site with w3c total cache running too. We are phasing out a multisite and moving the content to the main site. The apache documentation is not clear to me.

Comment: Show what exact URL you are starting with here, please.

Comment: The output you are seeing would not seem to be possible with the directives you've posted. This isn't something that changes in the server-config would have affected. More likely to be something with WordPress?